# Evitar que un dropdown se cierre con un datepicker

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, vue.js

Tengo un dropdown con un elemento `b-form-datepicker`. El problema es que cuando el usuario hace click en el `datepicker` el dropdown se cierra, y no sé como evitarlo. Para los inputs lo que usaba era esto: `@click.capture.native.stop` pero no sirve para el `datepicker`.
El código sería esto

```
<b-dropdown>
   <b-form-datepicker></b-form-datepicker>
</b-dropdown>
```

A su vez estuve leyendo la documentación de `b-dropdown-form` pero igualmente sigue sin quedarse abierto al hacer click en el `datepicker`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Investigación, análisis y pruebas

Tras alguna que otra búsqueda interesante
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En github "bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue" explicaban: [Dropdown - prevent closing after click on dropdown-item #1628](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/1628)

Adicionalmente [consejos / buenas prácticas con dropdown"](https://dev.to/victorronnow/dropdowns-in-vue-the-right-way-19j9)

Esto es lo mas parecido que he encontrado
[SIMULA la persistencia del dropdown "jugando" con el contenido del dropdown y mostrandolo de nuevo (actualizando el contenido)](https://codesandbox.io/s/l7wqoqpjv9?file=/src/dropdown-test.js)

Dificultad añadida de búsqueda por la existencia de "selectores de fechas con dropdown y no dropdown con selector de fehcas" :P
Como este caso [selector de fechas con dropdowns](https://codesandbox.io/s/mpklq49wp?file=/package.json) o el paquete de npm "datepicker-dropdown" que nada tienen que ver con la pregunta.

Llegado a este punto se me ocurrió activar el dropdown desde un botón externo que situas justo encima del dropdown como esto.
[Mostrar ocultar opciones del dropdown desde otro botón](https://dev.to/scottstern06/programmatically-opening-bootstrap-vue-dropdown-35ab) de tal forma se podría controlar mejor el mostrar y ocultar el dropdown, pero claro hablamos casi de un dropdown custom y se sale de la pregunta.

Como podrás observar, hay muchas cosas separadas, pero justo justo justo lo que tu requieres es casi imposible, sería un hack como te voy a mostrar a continuación, el problema es que lo veo muy inconsistente así que tampoco lo recomendaría para nada.

### "pequeño hack logrado"

Como comentario respecto al hack, existen 3 puntos exactos del datepicker "nativo" donde al hacer click cierra el dropdown, dos de ellos (uno el icono y otro el input de fecha seleccionado) que se pueden controlar con preventDefault y StopProgapagate.
El tercer punto donde se cierra el dropdown es un pequeño padding que tiene el icono, que además, no permite controlar el evento del dropdown "ni preventDefault ni stopPropagate" por lo que..el espacio entre el icono y el input, lo he machacado con CSS para casi disminuir a 0 la probabilidad de hacer click en ese área que cierra el dropdown.

Concretamente el área que he machacado con CSS, es el área "natural de activación del datepicker", pero, que al usarlo como no funciona "preventDefault ni stopPropagate", no permite controlar el cierre del dropdown y he decidido eliminar ese área y que no sea clicable.

Para sustituir el datepicker que debería abrirse pero que nos impide el correcto uso del dropdown y hemos machacado con css, he creado o simulado la ventana que abre ese datepicker de forma manual y le paso los datos al datepicker original.

De esta forma controlamos el (mostrar / ocultar) de cada parte por separado, tanto el propio dropdown como del calendario para el datepicker.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      date: null,
      isHidden: true,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    $("#customDatePicker svg").click((event) => {
      event.stopPropagation();
      this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
    });
    $("#customDatePicker__value_").click((event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
    });
  }
})
```

```css
  #customDatePicker {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #customDatePicker > svg {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 25px;
  }
  #customDatePicker__value_ {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-dropdown ref="dropdown" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">
    <b-dropdown-item class="dropdownItem" style="min-width: 318px;">
      <b-form-datepicker id="customDatePicker" v-model="date"></b-form-datepicker>
      <div id="customCalendar" v-if="!isHidden">
        <b-calendar v-model="date"></b-calendar>
      </div>
    </b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item class="dropdownItem" style="min-width: 318px;">
      Item 2
    </b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```

Como se puede observar es bastante feo e inconsistente, unas partes del datepicker se pueden controlar con los eventos usando "stopPrograpagion" pero no funciona "preventDefault" y viceversa.

### CONCLUSIÓN FINAL

Por experiencia, cuando algo que "parece común" no existe y cuesta tanto abordarlo, normalmente suele ser porque o no es rentable u otras personas ya se han pegado con ello y directamente han decidido cambiar el planteamiento del problema.

Creo que llegado el punto de valorar y tener en cuenta el (coste de tiempo / beneficio) mejor preguntarse:
¿Realmente este es mi problema?, es decir, ¿realmente mi problema es no poder meter un datepicker en un dropdown?

Analizando cada parte del problema, ¿Que nos aporta el dropdown?
Al final, es un efecto sencillo de JS que muestra u oculta una serie de elementos en linea, es decir, 1 botón, 1 div con un bucle y un efecto toggle con un par de estilos.

Solo me obligaría a usar el componente nativo como solicitas si me ofreciera otras muchas cosas que me ahorren tiempo, un tipo de dropdown enriquecido como podría ser [select2](https://select2.org/) y digamos que entonces si, necesitaría ese dropdown.

Por ejemplo, existen "dropdowns" con buscadores incluidos como la librería de selectores llamada "select2" que ofrece buscadores, chips y algunos comportamientos adicionales integrados en el mismo dropdown. Si fuera el caso se podría entender la necesidad de usar ese dropdown tan específico, en otro caso..

### Recomendación de solución

¿Ŕentaría "crear un dropdown" personalizado?
¿Quizás uno que extienda del core y "sobreescribir los eventos "listener activados"? Así controlar el dropdown a placer.

Yo diría que si,
Si el dropdown me produce dolores de cabeza y tan solo es un efecto de desplegar y mostrar elementos, me plantearía hacerme uno personalizado.

Por último y con relación de que comentas haberlo usado antes, te dejo este enlace de [@click.native.prevent or @click.stop.prevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49041779/vuejs-click-native-stop-possible), por si te da alguna idea adicional

"A veces menos, es más" :)

---

(UPDATE)

Justo hoy (2-Enero-2021) he visto una nueva publicación por parte de la comunidad `Angular Developers - JavaScript Mastermind for Professional Development by AngularJobs.com` con un repositorio que han publicado y he recordado esta pregunta, lo he visto interesante, quizás te ayude a completar, mejorar y/o enriquecer ese Dropdown ;)

[GitHub weblineindia/AngularJS-Dropdown](https://github.com/weblineindia/AngularJS-Dropdown)

Comment: Aunque no tengo experiencia real con Vue sí la tengo con Angular, y puedo decir que en cuanto hace falta que un componente tenga un comportamiento diferente al original, lo *normal* es crear un componente personalizado modificando el original para que se ajuste a las necesidades. Incluso si solo es para un único uso, nunca sabes cuando más vas a poder volver a usarlo, especialmente si es un componente un tanto **genérico** como es el caso aquí. Te evitas hacer *chanchullos* raros y ganas en reusabilidad!

Comment: Sería lo mismo hacerlo con o sin Jquery en este caso?
Es decir, usaste Jquery por mera comodida o es necesario utilizarlo

Comment: Por comodidad, al final JQuery es azucar sintáctico de JavaScript, se puede adaptar.